# Moving my MVC 4 application to a different database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to switch the database from local to my university one. I've tried changing the connection string in the web config and the connection string of the EDMX. The databases are exactly the same but it's giving me all sorts of errors.

This is one of the main errors that I get
Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'RoleId'.

Line 417:            var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

As the table names/field values etc are the same I was hoping it would be easy to switch Database :( Is there a way I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a separate DB for user accounts (ASP.NET identity)?

Comment: Nope, they are all on the same database. Everything is an absolute replica as I used the EDMX to generate the DB from my previous DB.